# How to show that $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\left[0,1-\frac 1n\right]=[0,1)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

"Any union of closed sets is a closed set" is a false statement. Find a counter example (hint: $I_n=[0,1-\frac1{n}]$).

How can I prove that the union of $I_n=[0,1-\frac1{n}]$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ is $[0,1)$?

Comment: Use the definition of set. A set is defined by their elements.

Comment: Clearly each $I_n$ is a subset of $[0,1)$, so $\cup I_n$ is also a subset of $[0,1)$. Conversely, if $x \in [0,1)$, then there is some $n$ with $x < 1-1/n < 1$, so $x \in I_n$ and hence $x \in \cup I_n$.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question but if $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a non-closed set then still $A = \cup_{x \in A} \{x\}$ is a union of closed sets.

Comment: the statement is false because he dosen't mention finite union

Answer (score 3):

To show that
$$\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\left[0,1-\frac1n\right]=[0,1)$$
you must show these two statements:

- If $x\in[0,1-1/n]$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, then $x\in[0,1)$. This
  should be easy.
- If $x\in[0,1)$ then there exists some $n\in\Bbb N$ such that
  $x\in[0,1-1/n]$. To show this, you can use the fact that $1-1/n\to
     1$, or write an equivalent proof.